# How I create a outlook object - new email - with electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, frontend

I'm looking for a solution to create a new mail object in Outlook app with node.js/electron for some automation. I can't use the office365 api (due to company security, very special) - so my last method is a programmatic access.

I searched a few days in Google to find a tutorial/answer, but I had no luck. :(

Does anyone have a good idea? I need rly help.

greetz claireSune

note:

- ActiveXObject is not possible with electron (chromium V8)